# Postgresql socket error when running Django's syncdb (mac OS 10.7.5)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to run Django's syncdb operation and am getting the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133870/postgresql-socket-error-on-osx-10-7-3-when-running-djangos-syncdb) and have tried the following:

- changing "listen_address" to "localhost" or "*" in /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data/potsgresql.conf

  changing "host" to "localhost" in my settings.py file (for Django)

  user is set to "postgres" with correct password in settings.py

(I restarted the postgresql server after each step.)

I've also checked my pg_hba.conf file to see if the Unix domain socket was accepting connections from all users (based on [this page](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/server/postgresql/configure-postgresql-accept-connections/)). Here's what I have there:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I never had this problem before. I somewhat recently upgraded to Lion and am working on a new virtualenv with the bare minimum of modules installed.

Comment: Have you tried `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`?

Comment: @okm Just gave it a try -- no luck, same response.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer courtesy of [Bradley Ayers](http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com/2011/07/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to.html?showComment=1351477812187#c5832541126778786188):

- set "unix_socket_directory" to "/var/pgsql_socket/" in postgres.conf

  executed following commands:

  - "$ sudo dscl . append /Groups/_postgres GroupMembership postgres"

    "$ sudo chmod g+w,o+rx /var/pgsql_socket/"

  restarted postgresql

Answer (score 0):

your database is not running try

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres  start
```

assuming thats where your postgre data directory is